# Добавление картинки в Java GUI

Tags: java, gui, swing

у меня в программе по клику на кнопку высветляется следующего типа сообщение

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Сообщение", "Информация о программе", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Можно ли как то в нем помимо текста "Сообщение" добавить как то картинку? Я искал информацию на
других сайтах и не нашел, как это реализовать в таком диалоговом окне, буду рад за подсказки.

Answer (score -1):

Да, можно. У showMessageDialog есть параметр для этого.

```
ImageIcon img= new ImageIcon("путь/к/картинке.png");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "текст", "инфо", JOptionPane.INFORMATION__MESSAGE, img);
```

Comment: а как картинке задать размер? пробую через         img.setSize(500, 500);
 и не работает

Comment: Никак, это будет иконка рядом с сообщением. Если нужно картинку большего размера, то showMessageDialog для этого вряд ли подходит